# Find the number of paths in Z³

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, combinations

Find all paths in\begin{equation}  \mathbb Z^3 
\end{equation} of 6 steps where each step consists in increase or decrease by 1 one of the coordinates where it is and that start and finish in the (0,0,0) point.

I have been on this problem and my solution is based in dividing the problem in 3 cases: When it only moves in one axis, when it moves in 2 axis and when it moves in 3 axis. However I would be grateful if someone could give a shorter solution.

Comment: With computer assistance this becomes easy.  Look at the constant in the expansion of $(x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1}+z+z^{-1})^6$.  [Plug it into a calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expand+%28x%2B1%2Fx+%2B+y+%2B+1%2Fy+%2B+z+%2B+1%2Fz%29%5E6).  Doing it by hand, perhaps your way was sufficiently easy and short.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that there was a link to the expansion

Answer (score 1):

Here is another looking at how many ways you can get to different positions after $3$ steps

$0$ steps

```
1
```

$1$ step

```
           1 
1      1   0   1      1
           1
```

$2$ steps

```
                              1
           2              2   0   2              2
1      2   0   2      1   0   6   0   1      2   0   2      1  
           2              2   0   2              2
                              1
```

$3$ steps

```
                                                         1  
                              3                      3   0   3
           3              6   0   6              3   0  15   0   3
1      3   0   3      3   0  15   0   3      1   0  15   0  15   0   1 ... 
           3              6   0   6              3   0  15   0   3
                              3                      3   0   3
                                                         1
```

and $6\times 1+ 24 \times 3+8 \times 6+6\times 15= 216 = 6^3$ as expected

but then you need to get back in the next three steps so the answer is

$$6\times 1^2+ 24 \times 3^2+8 \times 6^2+6\times 15^2= 1860$$

the same as JMoravitz's generating function method of looking at the constant in the expansion of $(x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1}+z+z^{-1})^6$.